# Flatten nested JSON arrays with inherits properties in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tree, nested

I have a big json/dictionary with different levels of nested json arrays, I would like to flatten it, and also capture the relationship of the structure,

Part of my json looks like:

```html
{
  "name": "root",
  "type": "all",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "properties",
      "type": "feature",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "print",
          "type": "feature",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "graphic print",
              "type": "feature",
              "inherits": true
            },
            {
              "name": "striped print",
              "type": "feature",
              "inherits": true,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "pinstriped",
                  "type": "feature",
                  "inherits": true
                },
                {
                  "name": "light stripe",
                  "type": "feature",
                  "inherits": true
                },
                {
                  "name": "wide stripe",
                  "type": "feature",
                  "inherits": true
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "colours",
      "type": "colour",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "main colours",
          "type": "colour",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "black",
              "type": "colour",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "light black",
                  "type": "colour",
                  "inherits": true
                },
                {
                  "name": "blue black",
                  "type": "colour",
                  "inherits": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "red",
              "type": "colour",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "bright red",
                  "type": "colour",
                  "inherits": true
                },
                {
                  "name": "light red",
                  "type": "colour"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "genders",
      "type": "gender",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "female",
          "type": "gender"
        },
        {
          "name": "male",
          "type": "gender"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The depth of nests is not all the same. I 
- want all the nodes (values of "name")
- also want all its parents if the node has "Inherit" key of True value.

Something like:

[image]

But if there are better ideas on how to store this data, will be happy to accept as well!

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do your need

```
def parse_dict_of_dict(_dict, _parent = '', ret_dict={}):
    _name, _children, _inherit = _dict["name"], _dict.get('children', None), _dict.get('inherits', False)
    if _children is not None:
        if isinstance(_children, list):
            for _child in _children:
                parse_dict_of_dict(_child, _name+ ', ' + _parent if _inherit else _name , ret_dict)
    ret_dict[ _name] = _parent.strip(' ').strip(',') if _inherit else None
    return ret_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate more on your output?

OR you can use this function to flatten a nested JSON to a simple JSON.

```
def parse_dict_of_dict(_dict, _str = ''):
    ret_dict = {}
    for k, v in _dict.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            ret_dict.update(parse_dict_of_dict(v, _str= _str+k+'_'))
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for index, item in enumerate(v):
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    ret_dict.update(parse_dict_of_dict(item,  _str=_str+k+'_%d_'%(index)))
                else:
                    ret_dict.update({k+'_%d'%(index): item})
        else:
            try:
                ret_dict[_str + k] = str(v)
            except Exception as e:
                ret_dict[_str + k] = unicode.encode(v, errors='ignore')
    return ret_dict
```

Comment: Thanks, the results only kept "name", and if there is "inherit", then find its upper layer/parent's "name". Does it make sense? I tried your code, it doesn't reflect the Inherit relations, which is what I have trouble on capturing.

Comment: In your output, "graphic print" parent shouldn't be "print, properties, root"?

Comment: No, since "print" doesn't have "Inherit" key, which is by default meaning False, only "graphic print" has "Inherit" which is to "print". Hence it only has 1 parent, which is "print".